# Unit Test Keeps failing on Pycharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I working on building some unit tests for my segmentation python scripts that I have created in pycharm. The issue here is whenever I run test, it keeps failing and in pycharm output terminal I get following message,

"'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

Can someone help me how to resolve this please?

Does it have to do something with environment variables?
As of now, this is what I have for Path environmnet variable: "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "Path environment variable" - do you mean that is the only path in PATH is this one? This would of course explain why it can't find `cmd`, though I doubt that this is really the case... maybe you mean additional paths set in PyCharm?

Comment: Thanks. What I mean by path environment here is, We have user variables and System variables under Environment variables, right?
Under System variables, we have variables like Path, PATHEXT, TEMP etc. The current value for Path is 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd' in my system. Not sure this is causing the error but just checking. If you have any other solution please let me know @MrBeanBremen

Comment: Well, you should at least have the default paths like `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%` - otherwise system files (like the command interpreter) will not be found. Can it be that you removed them somehow? Maybe while installing git?